# Extracting Headings/Chapters and related paragraphs separately from PDF file in Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, text-extraction, data-extraction, html-content-extraction

My task is to fetch chapter-wise content from pdf file separately so that i can store into database.
So far, i tried regex and tried to split but that only gives me chapter number but didn't help me in splitting the chapters. Next i tried BeatifulSoup library and converted to HTML format. Now i have each page in the list but how can i further split if i find a heading/chapter inside page. For example : If Heading is 1.1.2 then i want its content separately to saved into list. Same for 1.2.1, 2.3.1, 4.5.....

```
from tika import parser
from io import StringIO
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
if ext==".pdf":
    file_data=[]
    raw_xml = parser.from_file(text_path, xmlContent=True)
    xhtml_data = BeautifulSoup(raw_xml['content'], features="lxml")
    print(xhtml_data.prettify())
    for page, content in enumerate(xhtml_data.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'page'})):
    # Parse PDF data using TIKA (xml/html)
        _buffer = StringIO()
        _buffer.write(str(content))
        parsed_content = parser.from_buffer(_buffer.getvalue())
        _buffer.truncate()
        # Add pages
        text = parsed_content['content'].strip()
        file_data.append(text)
```

Comment: Any update on this? I have the requirement now, can you please help?

Comment: What challenge are you facing?

Comment: There is no fixed font size or fixed fonts to extract the text based on that. So iam looking for an intelligent system that can separate the headings and paragraphs.

Comment: Also i cannot write a regular expression, as the chapter headings do not have numbers.